# How to make a single TextView fade in and out with new text

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I am trying to use a single instance of the same TextView to achieve the following fading animation effect (by setting `textView.setText`):

1. `.setText` is set to "Welcome" on initialize
2. Fade Out
3. `.setText` to "How are you?"
4. Fade In
5. Fade Out
6. `.setText` to "How old are you?"
7. Fade In
8. Fade Out
9. And so on...

The effect is to fade new text in and then fade out. However I have tried many different ways, but can only achieve the above by using multiple TextView objects in the XML and Java class.

This is my current code:

```
textViewA.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textViewA.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(2000).start();
                textViewB.setText("Next Question");

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Then I have to keep repeating the above code, by setting the second `textViewB.setText` to the new text, then repeat the fading for each new `textView` object (`textViewA`, `textViewB`, `textViewC`, `textViewD`).

How can I achieve this with a single TextView?

**Note**: I have tried to simply fade out the `textView`, then use `textView.setText` whilst `alpha` is set to 0, then fade it back in to `alpha` set to 1, but as soon as I call the `textView.setText` method, the `textView` overrides the fader and appears immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a single TextView for the fade in and fade out animation you have to create two different `Runnable` `End Actions` one for `fadeInEndAction` and one for `fadeOutEndAction` and from each Runnable get the correct `ViewPropertyAnimator` to start the fade in or fade out.

Based on your example you can achieve this effect using a single TextView like below:

```
TextView tv;
String[] stringMessages = {"Welcome", "How are you?", "How old are you?"};
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    setText();
    getFadeOutViewPropertyAnimator().start();
}

private ViewPropertyAnimator getFadeInViewPropertyAnimator(){
    return tv.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(2000).withEndAction(fadeInEndAction);
}

private ViewPropertyAnimator getFadeOutViewPropertyAnimator(){
    return tv.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(2000).withEndAction(fadeOutEndAction);
}

private final Runnable fadeInEndAction = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //no more strings to show stop the fade-in/out loop here
        if(i == stringMessages.length){
            return;
        }
        getFadeOutViewPropertyAnimator().start();
    }
};

private final Runnable fadeOutEndAction = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setText();
        getFadeInViewPropertyAnimator().start();
    }
};

private void setText(){
    tv.setText(stringMessages[i++]);
}
```

**Result:**

[image: fadeInOut]